# Does Open CTI works in community

Tags: apex, community, lightning-community, opencti

Does Open CTI works in community ? 
I couldn't  find anything in the documentation of Open CTI right now.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To use Open CTI, you'll need more than a Community User License. If I'm not mistaken, it requires at least a Salesforce Platform license and more likely a Salesforce CRM license. Community users are "external" users, not internal users. Open CTI was developed for use by internal users.